# Can I use the output of mobile charger as a DC source for my circuit?

Tags: power-supply, charger, ac-dc

The title explains it all. Can I use the voltage and ground pins from the mobile charger and use it in my breadboard circuit? Is it safe? 
If it isn't, what is the thing I need to buy so as to convert 230V AC to 5V DC? I don't know the name of that thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

If the mobile charger is just a DC power supply (true in most cases I believe), then yes. You will be able to draw 5V at whatever current it can provide although it might have a minimum current in order to regulate correctly.

If the mobile charger contains the actual charging circuitry (as opposed to the phone) then no, because it will attempt to charge your circuit and apply various amounts of voltages, constant current, etc.

Comment: thanks. could u also edit your answer and tell me the name of the thing which converts 230V to 5V? I can't remember

Comment: It is highly unlike to have the second variant. I really can't remember even one case of cell phone, where the charger is actually in the "charger". Such chargers are more usual on other devices such as drills, electrical screwdrivers etc.

Comment: It's now 2022 and every mobile charger is a USB charger which supplies a steady 5V by default.